# Typescript: formatting nested type in interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, parsing

I have `interface CountersData` that I would like to model off of my JSON data. As seen below, I have a nested `id` (in example below `1830` and `1835` are `ids`) property that is a array of a nested dictionaries, which I also want to be *optional*.

I have been unable to make it optional, so I am unable to fetch the proper data. How should this data be formatted? See below my code and the JSON format.

```
interface CountersData {
  //other properties

  //want this to be optional
  [id: number]: {
    count_targets: number;
    count_targets_excluded: number;
    count_targets_pending: number;
    count_targets_in_progress: number;
    count_targets_completed: number;
    count_targets_failed: number;
  }[];

  [key: string]: number | string | any | undefined;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the property optional like this:

```
type CountersData = {
    [key in number]?: {
        count_targets: number;
        count_targets_excluded: number;
        count_targets_pending: number;
        count_targets_in_progress: number;
        count_targets_completed: number;
        count_targets_failed: number;
    }[];
} & { [key: string]: number | string | any | undefined };
```

Comment: how could you create an example of this custom type?